# MySQL query optimization. Many SELECT + INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, select

I have next table structure:
Games - contains base games info (sport events),
Bets - bet variations (team a wins, team b wins etc),
Votes - user choises of bet variations.

Next query shows list of all last bet variations for all not started games.
Some bets in list also contain some info if current user voted for it.

Inserted selects used for detect next: 1 - is user already voted for this bet?, 2 - get user's choise (yes\no), 3 - get user's vote amount.

```
SELECT bets.*, games.Time, games.TA, games.TB, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE BID=bets.BID AND UID=$UserID) AS Vt, 
  (SELECT YN FROM votes WHERE BID=bets.BID AND UID=$UserID) AS yn,
  (SELECT Pt FROM votes WHERE BID=bets.BID AND UID=$UserID) AS Pt
FROM bets
LEFT JOIN games ON games.GID = bets.GID
WHERE games.Yes=0 AND bets.Dl=0
ORDER BY bets.Time DESC
```

How can i optimize it?
How to get votes.YN and votes.Pt in one query?

Comment: Only the SQL is relevant, not the [broken] invocation of it.

Comment: BTW, that's an INNER JOIN!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `left join` is useless, because you are using a value in the second table.  So, I'll change it to `inner join` for clarity.

In addition, the subqueries for `YN` and `PT` have no aggregation, so it would seem that they could return more than one row.  I'm assuming there should be a `sum()`.

Then, I am moving the three correlated subqueries into the `from` clause.  This requires aggregating by `bid`:

```
SELECT bets.*, games.Time, games.TA, games.TB,
       coalesce(v.vt, 0) as vt, coalesce(v.yn, 0) as yn, coalesce(v.pt, 0) as pt
FROM bets inner join
     games
     ON games.GID = bets.GID left join
     (select bid, count(*) as vt, sum(yn) as yn, sum(pt) as pt
      from votes v
      where UID=$UserID
      group by bid
     ) v
     on v.bid = bets.bid
WHERE games.Yes=0 AND bets.Dl=0
ORDER BY bets.Time DESC;
```

EDIT:

Let me point out that this may or may not provide improved performance (depending on things like the selectivity of the `where` clause).  With a `left outer join` that keeps all the rows from `bets`, it probably would be better.

Adding the following index should fix the original version of the query:  `votes(bid, uid)`.

Comment: That's nice n Quick! You are one of my inspirations!

Comment: But where the User's identification (i need votes data for only bets were voted by current user), and also can you tell me for what you used SUMs?

Comment: @SirD . . . I've added that in, along with a `coalesce()` that puts a `0` instead of `NULL` when there are no votes.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I tried your implementation and that's what i get: 1. It worked fine but without a `coalesce()` - function does not exist. 2. There's no differences in performance with `left outer join`. 3. My implementation little faster than yours. Tested on 1100 rows. But thank you for lesson, i got more new experience =)

Comment: @GordonLinoff ohh sorry, i copy\pasted your code with error `coalese()`. Now your implementation faster then my (0,016 VS 0.028). Thank you!